# Securing ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: asp.net, api, web-services, asmx

I'm planning to develop a web service application to support an iPhone app and need to be able to secure communications between the application and certain asmx methods.  Having used APIs for Facebook, Twitter and the like - I was wondering how I might best accomplish this with ASP.NET.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The best way to do this is to not use a legacy web service infrastructure which has little support for security. By using ASMX, you're already on the wrong track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF has thorough support for different authentication schemes

Comment: And, in contrast, ASMX does not.